# use ask as a parameter in semantic media wiki

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

How can I pass an ask as a parameter of a query?

For example:

```
myvar={#ask: [[Category:City]][[London]]
|?population
|?currency
|}
```

Then use the data again in a custom function:

```
{#ask: [[England]]
|?population
|?currency
|capital=myvar
|}
```

If I try using something like the code below, when I debug the application, capital is equal to an empty String ( it's declared but empty ):

```
{#ask: [[England]]
|?population
|?currency
|capital={#ask: [[Category:City]][[London]]
         |?population
         |?currency
         |}
|}
```

Comment: First of all your ask syntax should be {{#ask: QUERY |?PRINTOUT }}.


Then I'm not sure what you are trying to do with '|captial=...'. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is not correct.

It should be like this:

```
{{#ask: [[Category:City]] [[located in::England]] 
| ?population 
| ?currency 
}}
```

You can have more informations about inline queries at the [Semantic MediaWiki website](https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Inline_queries).

And you can see how build nested queries at this question: [Semantic mediawiki #ask query: Displaying nested properties on the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273180/semantic-mediawiki-ask-query-displaying-nested-properties-on-the-same-query)

Hope that help you. Thanks!